# How to access and change the values of Resources in Resource Dictionary at runtime in Windows Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am migrating my Windows Phone 8 App to Windows Universal Apps. I have created a Resource Dictionary with some values in Windows 8.1 project and included its path in **App.xaml** file. Below is Resource Dictionary and App.xaml.

Resource Dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Styles">

<SolidColorBrush Color="#388941"
                 x:Key="AppBackGroundColor" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="White"
                 x:Key="PageTitleColor" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="White"
                 x:Key="AppFontColor" />
<SolidColorBrush Color="White"
                 x:Key="StatusColor" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application
x:Class="MyCouncilServices.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp">

<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Application-specific resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- 
                Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
             -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Styles.xaml"/>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now, I want to know how can I access this values in whole App and change its value in c# code.

I tried the same way as I did in Windows Phone 8 project as below but it was causing System.Argument Exception.

```
if(App.Current.Resources.ContainsKey("AppBackGroundColor"))
  {                      App.Current.Resources.Remove("AppBackGroundColor");
   }             App.Current.Resources.Add("AppBackGroundColor",GetColorFromHex(#FFFFFF));//Getting error at this line.System.ArgumentException ("An item with the same key has already been added.")
```

I want to use the Resources in my entire app.

Please can anyone suggest how can we access the resources from Dictionary and change its values.

Comment: are you sure with the braces? should those two lines come under the if?

Comment: @Utsav Please check , I edited my code. When I debug its going in if condition then the value for key AppBackGroundColor is removed and then when I add a new value to AppBackGroundColor its showing the error

Comment: What will happen if the code flow doen't enter the if statement? Can you add a resource which is already there without removing it? I think that you should place that statement inside the if clause. Also system.argument exception occurs when one or more arguments is not valid. So make sure you are giving proper arguments to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to remove and add, when you can simply overwrite. Just like this:

```
App.Current.Resources["AppBackGroundColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); // Red for example
```

Add this line to `OnLaunched()` method in **App.xaml** file at the beginning. I tried this and it works for me.